# Why is MATLAB returning different results for the same linear system?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I have this 4x4 system

[image]

where the variables are `Eor`, `Eot`, `Eo2r` and `Eo2t` (i.e., `Eo`, `d`, `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, `g2` and `g3` are known **complex** numbers).

I'm interested in finding not the variables themselves but these other values:

```
p_tot = Eor/Eo;
t_tot = Eot/Eo;
p_1 = Eo2r/Eo;
t_1 = Eo2t/Eo;
```

I tried to solve this using  MATLAB, as doing it by hand would be rather tedious.

The values of the constants are these:

```
e0 = 8.854187817*10^(-12);
u0 = 4*pi*10^(-7);
n0 = sqrt(u0/e0);

f = 10^9;
w = 2*pi*f;
d = 0.3;
tg_p = 0.23;

g2 = w*sqrt(u0*e0*9)*sqrt(1-i*tg_p);
g3 = w*sqrt(u0*e0);

n1 = n0;
n2 = w*u0/g2;
n3 = n0;
Eo = 1;
```

When I solve the linear system with this script

```
syms Eor Eo2t Eo2r Eot

eq1 = Eo+Eor == Eo2t + Eo2r;
eq2 = Eo-Eor == (n1/n2)*(Eo2t-Eo2r);
eq3 = Eo2t*exp(-i*g2*d)+Eo2r*exp(i*g2*d) == Eot*exp(-i*g3*d);
eq4 = Eo2t*exp(-i*g2*d)-Eo2r*exp(i*g2*d) == (n2/n3)*Eot*exp(-i*g3*d);

[SEor, SEo2t, SEo2r, SEot] = solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4] , [Eor, Eo2t, Eo2r, Eot]);
S = [SEor; SEo2t; SEo2r; SEot];

p_tot = double(SEor/Eo)
t_1 = double(SEo2t/Eo)
p_1 = double(SEo2r/Eo)
t_tot = double(SEot/Eo)
```

I get a completely different result from the one I get if I solve the system as Ax=b and then perform the MATLAB operation `A\b`:

```
A = [1  -1  -1  0;
     1  n1/n2 -n1/n2 0;
     0 exp(-j*g2*d) exp(j*g2*d) -exp(-j*g3*d);
     0 exp(-j*g2*d) -exp(j*g2*d) -exp(-j*g3*d)*(n3/n2)];

b = [-1;1;0;0];

S = A\b;

p_tot = S(1)/Eo
t_1 = S(2)/Eo
p_1 = S(3)/Eo
t_tot = S(4)/Eo
```

So the thing is that I'm getting two **different** results for the same problem using two different methods (which should be equivalent).

The results I'm getting are these:

**With the Ax = b method**:

```
p_tot =

  -0.5109 + 0.0436i


t_1 =

   0.4924 + 0.0427i


p_1 =

  -0.0032 + 0.0009i


t_tot =
   0.0284 + 0.0011i
```

**Directly solving the system**:

```
p_tot =

  -0.5011 + 0.0406i


t_1 =

   0.4956 + 0.0415i


p_1 =

   0.0033 - 0.0009i


t_tot =

   0.0866 - 0.0066i
```

What am I doing wrong and which one is the actual solution?

Comment: This is two separate questions: 1) is your math correct and 2) is MATLAB doing the math the way you think it is. As much as I'd love to double check your math for you, you should FIRST determine whether the error you are experiencing has to do with a problem on MATLAB's part or a problem on the part of your hand calculations. Are SURE that your hand calculations are correct? If you are, just explain what you're doing in MATLAB and clean up your question. If you aren't, then you should check your math or ask a question on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Could you show the answers that you got?  That might go partway toward addressing the issues raised in the other comment. Also, I'm unclear on what your third method really was. Please specify what you used for A, x, and b when you made that call.

Comment: @VladislavMartin There is not much math involved actually. It is just that system of 4x4, I didn't to anything by hand except for building the A and b matrices (which is pretty straightforward). The rest was just typing those 4 equations in MATLAB.

Comment: @Brick I just added that to the question.

Comment: I still don't follow you A\b method. No quickly enough clear to me where you got that value of b. The answers you provide, however, are not *completely* different. Many of the values are the same answer to answer - albeit given to different variables. I *suspect* that maybe your equations do not have a *unique* solution in this case, partly based on that observation and partly because there seem to be some special symmetries / special values here, like parameters equal to each other or equal to one that make the equations less complex than they initially appear.

Comment: @Brick I just found out that I had a mistake in one of the methods. I'm editing the question right now. Nevertheless, the Ax=b still doesn't work out. I got the values of b knowing that Eo = 1, then using the equations in the first image.

Comment: @Tendero Is the `A` matrix created correctly? Shouldn't `(n3/n2)` instead be `(n2/n3)` in the 4th row, 4th column? I can't off-hand tell whether the 1st row, 3rd column is the correct sign.

Comment: @VladislavMartin You are absolutely right! I didn't see that. Now it works as a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help! I've added the solution as an answer, if that's solved your problem sufficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `A` matrix, the value in the 4th row, 4th column doesn't reflect the system of equations you presented in your question.

Instead of `(n3/n2)` it should be `(n2/n3)`.